# How to save content edited on an html page to a Google sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I currently have code that pulls all information from a google sheet and displays it as an editable html in a modal dialogue box.
[image]

However, I am trying to find a way so that when I make the edits in one or multiple of the cells in the box, that it would write to the google sheet. However, I am lost on how I would begin to save the edited content and then overwrite the google sheet content with the new information. Any advice on the direction I should look would be greatly appreciated.

code.GS

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Jigs & Tools')
      .addItem('First item', 'displayHtmlViewer')
      .addToUi();
}

function include(filename) {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
        .getContent();
}

function displayHtmlViewer(file = "dashboard"){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file)
            .evaluate()
            .setHeight(2000)
            .setWidth(2000);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'J&T Dashboard');
}

function getData1(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg=ss.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid #111;}</style><table>';
  if(vA.length>0){
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      html+='<tr>';
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
        if(i==0){
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>', vA[i][j]);
        }else{
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', vA[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    html+='<table>';
  }
  Logger.log(html)
  return html;
}
```

dashboard.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!=include('CSS');?>
    <?!= include('res1') ?>

  </head>
  <script>
    function getData() {
      var rows = google.script.run.useDataRange();
      alert(rows);
    }
  </script>
   <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <div class="btnGroup1" style="width:100%">
        <button style="width:33%" button onclick="google.script.run.getLengthSS()">Filter Views</button>
        <button style="width:33%">Edit Filter Views</button>
        <button style="width:33%">Options</button>
      </div>
<div class="divider"/> </div>
      <div contenteditable><div id="table"></div></div>
    <?!= include('script1') ?>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

script1

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
      document.getElementById('table').innerHTML=hl;
    })
    .getData1();
  });
  console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

res1

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is similar to how you get the data, something like `google.script.run.UpdateData(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to update the Spreadsheet when the HTML table is updated.

In this case, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

#### HTML and Javascript side:

And, please modify `dashboard.html` as follows. `id` is added like `<div contenteditable id="sample">`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!=include('CSS');?>
    <?!= include('res1') ?>

  </head>
  <script>
    function getData() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(rows => alert(rows)).useDataRange();
    }

  </script>
   <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
      <div class="btnGroup1" style="width:100%">
        <button style="width:33%" button onclick="google.script.run.getLengthSS()">Filter Views</button>
        <button style="width:33%">Edit Filter Views</button>
        <button style="width:33%">Options</button>
      </div>
<div class="divider"/> </div>
      <div contenteditable id="sample"><div id="table"></div></div>
    <?!= include('script1') ?>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Please modify `script1` as follows. Added eventListener. By this, when the HTML table is edited and the focus is out, the script for updating Spreadsheet is run.

```js
<script>
  document.getElementById("sample").addEventListener("blur",function(){
    const values = [...document.getElementById("sampletable").rows].map(r => [...r.cells].map(c => c.innerText));
    google.script.run.setValues(values);
  });

  $(function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
      document.getElementById('table').innerHTML=hl;

    })
    .getData1();
  });
  console.log('My Code');
</script>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

In this case, please modify the function of `getData1` as follows. And, please add new function `setValues` for updating the Spreadsheet as follows. I added new function for updating Spreadsheet. And I added `id` to the table. And I thought that `html+='<table>';` might be `html+='</table>';`.

```js
function setValues(values) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function getData1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg = ss.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var html = '<style>td,th{border:1px solid #111;}</style><table id="sampletable">';
  if (vA.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
      html += '<tr>';
      for (var j = 0; j < vA[i].length; j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          html += Utilities.formatString('<th>%s</th>', vA[i][j]);
        } else {
          html += Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td>', vA[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    html += '</table>';
  }
  Logger.log(html)
  return html;
}
```

#### Note:

- In order to run the script for updating Spreadsheet, `input` event can be also used instead of `blur`. But, when `input` is used, even when only one character is edited in the cell, the script is run. So I used `blur`. In this case, when the cells are edited and the focus is out from the table, the script for updating Spreadsheet is run.
- By the way, in your `dashboard.html`, although `getData()` is not used, `google.script.run` doesn't return directly the value. Please be careful this. If you want to retrieve the values from Google Apps Script side, please use `withSuccessHandler` like your script `script1`.